# Spring boot loading nested property with Number as key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I have nested property in my spring boot application. For eg:

```
 topics:
  target:
    abc_1:
      12345678:
        key: value_1
      default:
        key: value_1
```

I try to access that value using `@Value` in my class like below:

```
@Value("${topics.target.abc_1.12345678.key}")
private String key;
```

But I'm getting the below exception while starting the application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '***': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'topics.target.abc_1.12345678.key' in value "${topics.target.abc_1.12345678.key}"

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
```

But surprisingly, when I try to load `topics.target.abc_1.default.key`, it works. Is there any restriction on having a number as a key in the properties in the nested structure?
I'm sure that key with number value works without any issue in non-nested structure.

Comment: There must be something else wrong (which you didn't post). This code [works fine](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/spel).

Comment: OP is using YAML though so not sure your sample project is an apples to apples comparison

Comment: Thanks for trying out. I tried with yaml with your repo. It returns the same error

Comment: @Mike like this: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/spel/commit/fd39bc4a32e38aa803483a0b2851d5357bd32760 ?

Comment: @Thiru can you create a repo so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Thanks!! yes. give me a moment

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yeah that's probably a better test. I tried with my own new repo (created using Initializr w/ Spring Boot 2.0.5 and no other deps) and the YAML OP provided worked fine.

Comment: Actually my variable was, something like this. `topics.target.abc_1.123456789.key`. It returns the same error

Comment: Figured out. The problem is with the underscore!!! Damn!! I have updated the question. When I dont have the underscore in the key, it works perfectly fine

Comment: Well, this is a pain, if you can I recommend you to change the underscore for a dash.

Comment: Thanks @lealceldeiro. I will do that

Comment: When you get a chance to, accept your answer.  Don't put "solved" in the title.

Comment: Sure. Thanks Makoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the **"_"**  in one of the keys `abc_1`.

After removing the "_" from the property, everything seems to work fine.